# ReactJS input type = "text" maxLength is not working when passed as props

Tags: reactjs, input, react-props, maxlength

I am trying to pass maxLength as props to  but it is not working. Can anyone helps out? Thank you!

Following is the two component:

```
 <Input
        id="creategroup-group-and-description-textfield"
        value={value}
        type="text"
        multiline={this.props.multiline}
        rowsMax={this.props.rowsMax}
        maxLength={this.props.maxLength}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      />



     <TextFieldWithTitle
          title="Group Name"
          maxLength={3}
          multiline={false}
          placeholder="e.g.Study and Workout"
        />
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your 2 components?

Comment: Hi! consider adding code snippets to your question and not their image.

Comment: I shared the code above

Comment: what are `Input` and `TextFieldWithTitle`? styled components? your own components? or what?

Comment: TextFieldWithTitle is the component I defined. And <Input> is the component from Material UI. These two components are in different files. <Input> is located in the render part of TextFieldwithTitle, which is a subcomponent of another main component.  I called  TextFieldWithTitle in the main Component file.. passing props back to the subcomponent file

Comment: Input from Material UI doesn't have a maxLength property (https://material-ui.com/api/input/).
Can you share the code of the other component?

Comment: I know it does not have a maxLength property. I searched online. People said if it is maxLength then it can work. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1517

Comment: Those are 2 different components ... The one you are using is from `Material UI`, and the one you mentioned in your comment is from `react-bootstrap`

Comment: you mean the solution link I sent? Yes.. maxLength is a React issue  not a React-bootstrap

Comment: So I cannot set maxLength to a React UI component?

Comment: You are using `Input` from a library called Material UI, but the one they are talking about in the link you sent is `Input` from another library called `react-bootstrap`

Comment: Thank you bro for helping me here. I fixed the issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer and decided put it here for the people who may have the same question in the future :)

Answer:
if you want to pass maxLength as a props in React. You should use:

```
inputprops = {{maxLength = num}} (note: num can be any positive num you want. No {} and "" needed.
```

Then, in the place that receives this props, write:

```
inputprops = {this.props.inputprops}
```

To limit the input length, write:

```
<Input 
inputprops={{maxLength: 100(e.g.)}}
/>
```

NOTE: Inputprops and inputprops are two different things in React. Be careful.